# What is a Target Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Target Word™.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| Target Words™ | Not Target Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| TELL | SAY |
| BOIL | POACH |
| TARD | LATE |
| BLINK | WINK |
| JOB | TASK |
| ARGS | PARAMS |
| GRATE | GRIND |
| OIL | WATER |
| NILE | GANGA |
| JOIN | LEAVE |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Target Words™,Not Target Words™
TELL,SAY
BOIL,POACH
TARD,LATE
BLINK,WINK
JOB,TASK
ARGS,PARAMS
GRATE,GRIND
OIL,WATER
NILE,GANGA
JOIN,LEAVE
```

Hint 1:

> [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Target Word is:

> A word whose letters can be found sequentially on a regulation dartboard whose numbers have been converted into A1Z26. Acceptable moves between letters/numbers include (1) moving to the next letter/number clockwise, (2) moving to the next letter anti-clockwise, (3) moving through the bullseye to the letter/number directly opposite, and (4) staying on the same letter/number for a second use.

The usual arrangement for such an object is (clockwise from top):

> 20 - 1 - 18 - 4 - 13 - 6 - 10 - 15 - 2 - 17 -
>  3 - 19 - 7 - 16 - 8 - 11 - 14 - 9 - 12 - 5, then back to 20.

Which translates to:

> T - A - R - D - M - F - J - O - B - Q -
>  C - S - G - P - H - K - N - I - L - E, then back to T.

All the listed words can be found via this method:

> TARD, JOB and NILE are found clockwise.
>  TELL is found anti-clockwise.
>  BOIL,  OIL and JOIN are made by leaping across the bull from O to I.
>  BLINK is made by leaping across the bull from B to L.
>  ARGS is made by leaping across the bull from R to G.
>  GRATE is made by leaping across the bull from G to R.

As for the name:

> In darts, the dartboard is the TARGET.

And the clue...

> A 'white horse' is a darts term in the 'Cricket' variant of the game, when a player hits 3 different scoring trebles with their first set of 3 darts...

Comment: You also done a "hat trick", like the horse in the photo :P

Comment: @Conifers Ha, I suppose I have!